# Test if model contains some attribute and its value

Tags: java, spring, junit4

I am trying to implement a simple test for [Java Spring Framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/). Below is my code.

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someMapping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String toTestMethod(Model model)
{
   model.addAttribute("test", 1);
   return "test";    
}
```

Controller Test:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup()
{
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

@Test
public void testMethodTest() throws Exception
{
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/someMapping"))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(model().attribute("test", 1));
}
```

Application context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
    {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

When I run this test, it fails with the following exception

`java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'test' expected:<1> but was:<null>`.

I have no idea why this happens, can someone please clarify?

If needed, I will provide any additional information.

Comment: Seems you shared not valid code snippet. Because you can't return a String `test`, while requires `org.springframework.ui.Model`

Comment: What's the `Model`class? What does the compiler says about returning the `String` "test" in a method declared to return a `Model`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to change it back when I was trying something. See the edited question.

Comment: Please verify that your `Controller` is configured for test context.

Comment: What do you mean, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case the problem was in the `setup()`, now it looks like this:

```
@Before
public void setup()
{

    //        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();

    MyController ctrl = new MyController();
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(ctrl).build();
}
```

It started working as expected after this change.